# Does this thread-local Flask-SQLAchemy session cause a "MySQL server has gone away" error?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a web application that runs long jobs that are independent of user sessions. To achieve this, I have an implementation for a thread-local Flask-SQLAlchemy session. The problem is a few times a day, I get a `MySQL server has gone away` error when I visit my site. The site always loads upon refresh. I think the issue is related to these thread-local sessions, but I'm not sure.

This is my implementation of a thread-local session scope:

```
@contextmanager
def thread_local_session_scope():
    """Provides a transactional scope around a series of operations.
    Context is local to current thread.
    """
    # See this StackOverflow answer for details:
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/18265238/1830334
    Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
    threaded_session = Session()
    try:
        yield threaded_session
        threaded_session.commit()
    except:
        threaded_session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        Session.remove()
```

And here is my standard Flask-SQLAlchemy session:

```
@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    """Provides a transactional scope around a series of operations.
    Context is HTTP request thread using Flask-SQLAlchemy.
    """
    try:
        yield db.session
        db.session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print 'Rolling back database'
        print e
        db.session.rollback()
    # Flask-SQLAlchemy handles closing the session after the HTTP request.
```

Then I use both session context managers like this:

```
def build_report(tag):
    report = _save_report(Report())
    thread = Thread(target=_build_report, args=(report.id,))
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    return report.id

# This executes in the main thread.
def _save_report(report):
    with session_scope() as session:
        session.add(report)
        session.commit()
        return report

# These executes in a separate thread.
def _build_report(report_id):
    with thread_local_session_scope() as session:
        report = do_some_stuff(report_id)
        session.merge(report)
```

**EDIT: Engine configurations**

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://<username>:<password>@<server>:3306/<db>?charset=utf8'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE'] = 3600
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
```

Comment: can you also post engine configurations

Comment: @Busturdust, I've added them. I don't do anything else. Flask-SQLAlchemy handles everything else.

Comment: in my case, the scoped sessions, pool_recycle, and teardown_request were all required. I appear to be running stable in development so far. for Flask-SQLAlchemy, you MAY not need the teardown, but I can't be sure

Comment: My understanding is that Flask-SQLAlchemy provides a scoped session that's local context is the thread responding to the HTTP request--and that that session is open and closed for you. I'll do more reading to see if that's not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding an

`app.teardown_request(Exception=None)`

Decorator, which executes at the end of each request. I am currently experiencing a similar issue, and it seems as if today I have actually resolved it using.

```
@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception=None):
    Session.remove()
    if exception and Session.is_active:
        print(exception)
        Session.rollback()
```

I do not use `Flask-SQLAlchemy` Only Raw `SQLAlchemy`, so it may have differences for you.

From the Docs

> The teardown callbacks are special callbacks in that they are executed
>   at at different point. Strictly speaking they are independent of the
>   actual request handling as they are bound to the lifecycle of the
>   RequestContext object. When the request context is popped, the
>   teardown_request() functions are called.

In my case, I open a new `scoped_session` for each request, requiring me to remove it at the end of each request (`Flask-SQLAlchemy` may not need this). Also, the teardown_request function is passed an `Exception` if one occured during the context. In this scenario, if an exception occured (possibly causing the transaction to not be removed, or need a rollback), we check if there was an exception, and rollback.

If this doesnt work for my own testing, the next thing I was going to do was a `session.commit()` at each teardown, just to make sure everything is flushing

---

UPDATE : it also appears MySQL invalidates connections after 8 hours, causing the Session to be corrupted.

set `pool_recycle=3600` on your engine configuration, or to a setting < MySQL timeout. This in conjunction with proper session scoping (closing sessions) should do it.

Comment: Unfortunately due to the inconsistent nature of my issue and time it takes to recreate, I am still testing this -_-

Comment: I'll test this (and accept your answer in a few days if it works) but in the mean time can you explain what you think this does?

Comment: @gwg edited answer. I hope it works for you, I myslef am in the middle of this annoying issue!

Comment: That makes sense, but I already wrap my transactions in `try`/ `except`s, and I always close them in a `finally` statement... I'll look into this more, though. I will pay attention to if this issue is caused by exceptions in the context-threads.

Comment: Maybe I need to call `rollback` on the `Session` rather than my `threaded_session`.

Comment: the `try / except` Are related to the `request handling` i believe, and not necesarily the `request context` There is something in the context that is not getting rolled back by your context manager within the request handling, and when it leaves context it is throwing the error

Comment: I just checked on my stuff. Flask-Admin was down. I changed some of the code to start with a commit, and rollback if exception.

Comment: No, it's still happening. So you resolved it by using pure SQLAlchemy, and calling `Session.remove()` on application teardown?

Comment: @gwg for me, it was a combination of adding `pool_recycle` as well as the `teardown` AND context managed `scoped_session`

Comment: For me, it was an integration point between `Flask-Admin` that was causing an issue, which is why I went with the `teardown` in the first place, since I was not managing the responses manually

Comment: I had this issue come back for me, I resolved it again by instead of using a  `contextmanager` I use the implicit access of the `scoped_session`, leveraging the teardown to ensure rollbacks and commits instead of the contextmanager.

Comment: I feel like it's something else for me. I have another web application in production for over a year that doesn't have this issue. It just uses a standard scoped session from SQLAlchemy's documentation: https://github.com/MaayanLab/geo2enrichr/blob/master/g2e/db/utils.py

Comment: The use of the `contextmanager` + the `teardown` seems to be mimicing the same responsibility. you might want to try leaving a teardown to handle your context and instead of using the `contextmanager session` use the implicit access of the `scoped_session`  relying on the teardown to handle rollbacks and removals..... Unfortunately I do not use `Flask-SQLAlchemy` and you are right in the fact it should handle it for you

Comment: Also, you set `pool_recycle` on the application session, but I am not sure if `threaded_session` also has the `pool_recycle` setting, as it appears to be  using a custom factory and not the application session

Comment: I've not forgotten this thread. So I finally was able to implement some of your suggestions, and things look O.K. It's only been half a day, but typically the issue happens more frequently. I'll let you know / accept your answer in a few days, if things continue like this.

Comment: it was a doozy for me, but I've running clean since I moved to the implicit use of the `scoped_session` + the teardown

Comment: I experimented with a number of things over the past couple of weeks, but I think what did it was setting `pool_recycle` to less than MySQL's timeout. I had assumed our server's timeout was the default (8 hours) but when I finally checked it was 10 minutes. I set `pool_recycle` to 8 minutes, and it's been fine for 4 days.

Comment: @gwg, Thank you a lot. I believe you are talking about `wait_timeout` on mysql server. it is 300 on my deploy environment. By the way, I do not use flask-sqlalchemy neither. I use flask-sqlalchemy-session.

Comment: i'm getting this issue with Flask-SQLAlchemy and MariaDB. Current MariaDB `wait_timeout` is 1800 (i've not changed it) on 10.3.23 on ubuntu18.04, and it looks like Flask-SQLAlchemy sets the `pool_recycle` to 7200 for MySQL. It's looking promising to reduce this!