# Flask Internal Web App Dies after a while running on python

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, flask, flask-mysql

I have a web app meant for internal use only.
I wrote this app in Python 2.7 using Flask and flask-mysql. This app returns data from our MySQL database and returns some fields in a table in HTML. (It is very simple)

Now I am not a programmer and dont know too much on debugging, but I have this problem that the app runs perfect but left for a while it dies.(mostly at night or weekends when I guess it is not used).

Is there any way that I can keep it running, or that when it dies, it should restart.

I will paste my code if needed.

Arnoux

Comment: Use Supervisor and Gunicorn to serve your app and to restart dying processes. Also use logs to see why its crashing. Try Heroku if this is too much a challenge.

Comment: im running sentry currently, and I will use those other two then to restart when it dies ! thank you

Comment: is there an error message associated with its death?

Comment: No. It just dies. It seems as if my connection closes permanently and doesnt re-open after some inactivity. Sentry also didnt give an error when it died

Answer (score 1):

MySQL invalidates stale connections after 8 hours. Try adding a `pool_recycle=3600` to your engine configuration. Also, make sure you are properly managing your session. See this previous thread about the `MySql has gone away` error.

[Does this thread-local Flask-SQLAchemy session cause a "MySQL server has gone away" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684554/does-this-thread-local-flask-sqlachemy-session-cause-a-mysql-server-has-gone-aw/34684717#34684717)

Comment: Okay that seems like the correct way of approaching this. However I dont use SQLalchemy. I use flask-mysql. Do you perhaps know if the same can apply for flask-mysql?

Comment: I believe it as a mysql consideration regardless of the connector. There are default timeouts set in mysql (usually 8 hours), you need to make sure to refresh your connection before the timeout causing you to go stale. Check your MySQl configurations `wait_timeout` and other timeout values