# SQLAlchemy: How to bind scoped session to request

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy

I am new to sqlalchemy and it seems that I still miss several fundamental concepts. I want to use sqlalchemy to handle db interaction in a multi-thread web application.

So I start with

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy                 import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm             import sessionmaker, scoped_session

engine          = create_engine('mysql://mydb')
session_factory = sessionmaker( autocommit  = False,
                                autoflush   = False,
                                bind        = engine )
Session         = scoped_session(session_factory)
```

I use a `MoinMoin` wiki that handles the requests, so I have an object `macro.request` containing the request.

I now have a method in some class, say

```
def do_sth():
    session = Session()
    # use the session to get some data from the db
```

> Where and how do I tell the `Session` object which request it is linked to?

Reading [Multi-threaded use of SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297404), it says

> The ScopedSession object by default uses [threading.local()] as storage, so that a single Session is maintained for all who call upon the ScopedSession registry, but only within the scope of a single thread. Callers who call upon the registry in a different thread get a Session instance that is local to that other thread.

so " Callers who call upon the registry in a different thread get a Session instance that is local to that other thread."

> How is a Session instance local if I never told it which request it is linked to?

Answer (score 3):

The [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html#thread-local-scope) says

> So our above example of scoped_session usage, where the same Session object is maintained across multiple calls, suggests that some process needs to be in place such that mutltiple calls across many threads don’t actually get a handle to the same session. We call this notion thread local storage, which means, a special object is used that will maintain a distinct object per each application thread. Python provides this via the threading.local() construct.

So even though I have not figured out how to obtain the current thread's `pid` from the given session, the `threading` module is used to link the session to the thread. In particular, one can check the session's [hash key](https://sourcecodebrowser.com/sqlalchemy/0.5.7/classsqlalchemy_1_1orm_1_1session_1_1_session.html#a9a9fd8a27109dfccfb6d9c6b5376e9b9)

```
session.hash_key
```

in the example in the question to test that `Session()` provides the same session in two calls if and only if both were made in the same thread.

So in summary, the sessions are linked properly to the requests as long as every request is handled by its own thread.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the documentation!