# Using sqlalchemy in a multi-threaded cmd-line application

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am using sqlite with sqlalchemy.core i.e. not using session
There is a single table

can multiple-threads access and insert in that table using sqlalchemy.core?
I see that there is a SingleThreadPool, and it seems that engine.connect returns a thread_local connection?

If I use do engine.connect each time using an insert, is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18265238).
Which explains that you should use `ScopedSession` when multi-threading is required. This takes care of maintaining single session per thread.