# Flask: how to write to SQLAlchemy DB when multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, flask, sqlalchemy, python-multithreading

I am using multithreading in a Flask app and want each thread to append to an entry in a database. However, I can never get this to work. Per [Multi-threaded use of SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297404/multi-threaded-use-of-sqlalchemy) I have something like the following:

```
def test(arg):
    some_session.execute(text('update testtable set value = value||"a" where id == 1'))
    some_session.commit()

with app.test_request_context():
    executor.map(test,'arg')
```

This would call the `test()` function in multiple threads, and ideally each one would add 'a' to a row on the database with the id of 1, but it never works. If I just run `some_session.execute(text('update testtable set value = value||"a" where id == 1'))` and `some_session.commit()` normally without it being in a function that's running in multiple threads, this works just fine.

Here's my complete test code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_session import Session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session

from flask_executor import Executor

import concurrent.futures

from sqlalchemy.sql import text

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///testdb.sqlite3'
app.config.from_object(__name__)
Session(app)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///testdb.sqlite3', echo=True)
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
some_session = Session()

executor = Executor(app)

class testtable(db.Model):
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    value = db.Column(db.String(100))
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        
db.create_all()

entry = testtable('x')
db.session.add(entry)
db.session.commit()

# works
some_session.execute(text('update testtable set value = value||"PLEASEHELP" where id == 1'))
some_session.commit()
  
def test(arg):
    some_session.execute(text('update testtable set value = value||"y" where id == 1'))
    some_session.commit()
    
with app.test_request_context():
    executor.map(test,'arg')
    
Session.remove()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug = True)
```

How should this be done properly?

Comment: Have you tried creating and removing sessions _inside_ the test function?