# Is sqlalchemy sessionmaker thread safe?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Instead of:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

# an Engine, which the Session will use for connection
# resources
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///...')

# create session and add objects
with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add(some_object)
    session.add(some_other_object)
    session.commit()
```

I create a sessionmaker (according to example in documentation, see bellow):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# an Engine, which the Session will use for connection
# resources, typically in module scope
engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/')

# a sessionmaker(), also in the same scope as the engine
Session = sessionmaker(engine)

# we can now construct a Session() without needing to pass the
# engine each time
with Session() as session:
    session.add(some_object)
    session.add(some_other_object)
    session.commit()
```

Can I use the sessions from session maker in different threads (spawning multiple sessions at the same time)? In other words, is session maker thread safe object? If yes, can multiple sessions exists and read/write into same tables at the same time?

Furthermore, what is the advantage of of using 'scoped_session' - is it realated to problem of multiple sessions (one per thread)?:

```
# set up a scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=some_engine)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)

# now all calls to Session() will create a thread-local session
some_session = Session()

# you can now use some_session to run multiple queries, etc.
# remember to close it when you're finished!
Session.remove()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi-threaded use of SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297404/multi-threaded-use-of-sqlalchemy)

Comment: @Mark I edit my question to address my confusement and why I cannot relate to the suggested question.

Answer (score 1):

Session objects are not thread-safe, but are thread-local. What I recommend using is `sessionmaker` instead of `Session`. It will yield a Session object every time you need it, thus not idling the database connection. I'd use the approach below.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, Session

DB_ENGINE = create_engine('sqlite:///...')

DB_SES_MAKER = sessionmaker(bind=DB_ENGINE)

def get_db():
    db = DB_SES_MAKER()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

Then call `get_db` whenever needed:

```
db = next(get_db())
```