# Thread-safe application with sqlalchemy, postgresql

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, thread-safety

Is it possible to use sqlalchemy for threaded applications?
I have an app that creates new thread tasks. Can I use session in those threads?
I have read that using scoped_session in sqlalchemy might help. Should I use scoped_session or basic session with PostgreSQL?
I need to create a new connection for each thread.
Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to pass a single session across multiple threads? Or are you trying to create a session for each thread?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi-threaded use of SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297404/multi-threaded-use-of-sqlalchemy)

Comment: Currently, I am passing scoped session across multiple threads. My question is, how do I create a new session for each thread? Does scoped session create a new connection for each thread?

Comment: A non-scoped_session will provide that for you. Let me elaborate in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, a [`Session`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html) is thread specific. In contrast, a [`scoped_session`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/contextual.html#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session)  allows you to create session objects which share state between threads.

To answer your question specifically, when your application creates a `session` (or connection), resources for that connection are managed by a resource pool. Each thread your application opens will open a new connection, and [be independent of the others](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#is-the-session-thread-safe). (Unless explicitly designed otherwise.)

Comment: So I should open new session for each new thread?

Comment: If your application is explicitly multithreading, then yes, create a new session in each invocation. If your application is implicitly multithreading (ex: wsgi server), then new sessions with automatically be instantiated.

Comment: What does "implicitly" and "explicitly" multithreading means?